# I have no access to my Internal hard drive or the root file(if that matters)

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, root

I overwritten windows and am all in on Ubuntu.

I have 2 issues or at least one issue and one question.

My Ubuntu won't give me access to one of my Internal hard drives. - Luckely the small one.

Pic of what it says
[image]

I am not user #999 and I have no clue who he is. 
But I think I know what I did. Before I killed windows, I formatted this specific drive of an Ubuntu bootable USB.

How can I regain control of this drive?  - it's a SSD if it matters.

Then just on a side note question: I have a pc with secure boot and I see that I do have the shim and grub efi. I know what they do but what I can't seem to figure out is: Should I have both, can I do without the one(grub), or does it do any kind of damage to have both?

This is a pic of how they look under c
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I feel kind of stupid for posting the question. At least one part of my question I figured out.

**Do this is your installed Ubuntu**

CTRL + ALT + T = Opens the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Press enter and then enter your password - This will obviously not show in terminal.

Close down terminal and go to the Unity, and open Gparted.

Select the hard drive you want to take control of, and delete the partition(s)

Restart Ubuntu and get back into Gparted.

Create a new partition and mount it.

I have control of my hard drive again.

**Notes:** I am not sure if this will be the solution for you, if you have data you want to keep on your hard drive, but this worked perfectly for my situation.

This also didn't solve the root of my problem - root file

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187997/i-cant-access-the-root-folder This answers the question about root perfectly.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/621968/refind-showing-3-ubuntu-efi-instead-of-2 Just the title of this question pretty much answers my last question